# Vite build error: Error: 'pushScopeId' is not exported

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

I have a project using `"vite": "^2.9.12"`, `"vue": "^3.2.37"`, and `"typescript": "~4.7.4"`. The project is importing another repository of Vue components as an NPM package. A component is being imported into the main project:

```
import Btn from "thepackage/button/Btn.vue";
export default {
  components: { Btn },
};
```

and is using the component:

```
<btn>Hello World</btn>
```

The component shows up correctly when just running `vite` and viewing on `localhost:3000`. However, when running `vite build` The following error is thrown:

```
error during build:
Error: 'pushScopeId' is not exported by ../thepackage/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js, imported by ../thepackage/button/Btn.vue
```

Why is this error occuring? Is there a known fix?

Comment: Just ran into this issue too, did you find a fix?